# Why does azure arm template need both location and "locationName"?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

I was attempting to create a basic non-clustered Cosmos DB instance using the Azure ARM template generated by the portal.
I had no problems creating the database using the template and Powershell. However, what struct me odd was that the ARM template relies on both the short location code (e.g. ukwest) and the display name (e.g. UK West)

I would have expected the ARM templates to consistently use just one system of location codes, i.e. ukwest.

#### Screen capture from template file

[image]

#### Screen capture from parameters file

[image]

What was the design intent here?

Thanks

Comment: You'd have to ask the Azure team. No one here can answer this.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Actually, this is easy to answer @DanielMann :)

Locations array - is the locations where cosmos db is supposed to replicate itself. since its only a single region in your case it doesnt make a lot of sense, but if you'd had multiple ones - it would make sense. And for the naming - they probably chosen to call it `locationname` so its less confusing.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cosmos-db-resource-provider/databaseaccounts/createorupdate#location
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cosmos-db-resource-provider/databaseaccounts/createorupdate

Comment: I understand the significance of `locationName`.  The deeper intent of my question was why does ARM template not follow a conistent region naming system. I would have expected `uaenorth` to be used for both `location` and `locationName`. But, when I see `UAE North` - this breaks my mental model.

Comment: you can replace that with `uaenorth` and it will work just fine. you can also replace both with `uae north`. you do realize thats the same thing, right?

Comment: Yes. It does. I have tested and ARM deployment through PowerShell works if I set `locationName` to either `westus` or `West US` . This was not obvious to me because the ARM templates that gets generated from the Azure portal had different location conventions for `location` and `locationName` fields in the `parameters.json` file . Thank you.